# Get file type Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Hey everyone I'm trying to get the file type in Node.js. I have to rename the file before it's uploaded for version control and once the file is written then run some processing on it.

I'm aware that I can check the file type on the client but I still think it would be beneficial to do a server side check as well.

Other solutions have popped the file extension off the file name:

```
return filename.split('.').pop();
```

But since I'm renaming this file and a user could simply rename a malicious file to a whitelisted extension I'm looking for a solution that actually determines the file type, specifically CSV.

Can anyone point me in the direction of solving this?

Comment: what file extension do you need to support?

Comment: @ManuelSpigolon just CSV

Comment: You can use `path.extname(fullnameofthefile)`

Comment: CSV is an entirely text-based formula so it's hard to check if something is actually csv. You can check if it's all ASCII though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read the file extension you may use the snippet:

```js
const { extname } = require('path')

console.log(extname('foo.csv')) // .csv
console.log(extname('BAR.CSV')) // .CSV
```

> But since I'm renaming this file and a user could simply rename a malicious file to a whitelisted extension I'm looking for a solution that actually determines the file type, specifically CSV.

Usually, to implement this check, you need to read the magic bytes of the file and act accordingly for a limited set of [file types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures) but CSV is not in this list.

CSV is a plain text with a defined format, so you could:

- read some line an try to parse them
- define that the CSV must have a defined header like `id,col1,col2,etc`
- use some tools that try to guess the mime type of the file (like [`mime-types`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mime-types) )